# Dissector for TCP Option

Tags: tcp, lua, wireshark, wireshark-dissector

I am new to writing dissectors in Lua and I had two quick questions. I have a packet which has the TCP Options as MSS, TCP SACK, TimeStamps, NOP, Window Scale, ***Unknown***. I am basically trying to dissect the unknown section in the TCP Options field. I am aware that I will have to use the chained dissector.

The first question is while using the chained dissector to parse the TCP Options, do I have to parse all the Options from the beginning. For Example will I need to parse MSS, TCP SACK, .... and then finally parse Unknown section or is there any direct way for me to jump to the Unknown section.

The second question I have is I have seen the code for many custom protocol dissectors and if I need to dissect a protocol which follows (for example)TCP, then I will have to include the following:

```
-- load the tcp.port table
tcp_table = DissectorTable.get("tcp.port")
-- register our protocol to handle tcp port
tcp_table:add(port,myproto_tcp_proto)
```

My question is, is there anyway for me to jump to the middle of the protocol. For example in my case I want to parse TCP Options. Can I directly call tcp.options and the parser will start dissecting from where the options will start?

Answer (score 0):

The TCP option is "uint8_t type; uint8_t len; uint8_t* data" structure.
I usually give common used ones a name. For example getSack(), getMss().
For others, keep them in an array(maximum size like 20).

For your second question, you mean you don't care about TCP header, right? If so, just move your pointer 20 bytes further to get access the TCP options.